Serving a Torch-TensorRT model with Triton
I'm trying to use a Torch-TensorRT model with Triton Inference Server for deployment. I'm following an example from the official PyTorch tutorial
https://pytorch.org/TensorRT/tutorials/serving_torch_tensorrt_with_triton.html
However, encountering below error when trying to save the compiled TensorRT model.
import torch_tensorrt
torch.hub._validate_not_a_forked_repo=lambda a,b,c: True

# load model
model = torch.hub.load('pytorch/vision:v0.10.0', 'resnet50', pretrained=True).eval().to("cuda")

# Compile with Torch TensorRT;
trt_model = torch_tensorrt.compile(model,
    inputs= [torch_tensorrt.Input((1, 3, 224, 224))],
    enabled_precisions= { torch.half} # Run with FP32
)

# Save the model
torch.jit.save(trt_model, "model.pt")

Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/scratch_space/model.py", line 15, in <module>
    torch.jit.save(trt_model, "model.pt")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/jit/_serialization.py", line 83, in save
    m.save(f, _extra_files=_extra_files)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1893, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(
AttributeError: 'GraphModule' object has no attribute 'save'

I'm running above code from NVIDIA's Pytorch container nvcr.io/nvidia/pytorch:24.08-py3
Can someone please help?
